# Increment name of int by 1

Tags: c#, .net

If I declare an integer:

```
int house = number;
```

How can I get the name to increment by 1 within a forloop (+1 to the name of house):

e.g.

```
 int house1 = number[i];
 int house2 = number[i];
 int house3 = number[i];
```

Comment: You want an array.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Even if it were possible, you would never be able to reference them.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive by doing that?

Comment: You need to use a dynamic language for that kind of thing. Otherwise just populate an array with your Houses and do it that way.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You would need to generate code at compile time.

You should be using an array, not a set of similarly named variables.

But you can always use a collection like:

```
Dictionary<int, int> houses = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach( ... )
    houses.Add(i+1, number[i]);
```

Comment: @yeeeh We don't know what your actual problem is, so we can't really say.

Comment: i'm guessing
 int[] houses;    or a dictionary that works too depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use a Dictionary

```
var houses = new Dictionary<string, int>
for(int i=1; int < 10; int++)
{
   string houseNumber = "house" + i;
   houses[houseNumber] = number[i];
}
```

Then you can refer to them by houses["house1"], houses["house2"], and so on...

Comment: I wouldn't really *recommend* that approach, in that this question was presumably being asked based on him not knowing that it was the wrong approach. Though yes, if he really *did* need to be able to reference them by strings "house[n]" rather than just by their indices, a Dictionary would make sense. But wouldn't it make more sense to just reference a house by its index?

Comment: I don't think that's really worthy of a mark down - I've just deleted my post saying the same thing and as far as I am concerned it is a way of doing exactly what the OP has requested

Comment: It would make more sense to me, but it looks like he already knows what an array is, so I assumed that a regular array wouldn't work for his purposes.  I took his question at face value.  Which is hardly a reason to downvote, whoever did that...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increment the variable names. You create an array instead.

```
int[] houses = {1,2,3,4};

for(int i = 0; i < houses.length; i++){
   Console.WriteLine(houses[i]);
}
```